# Filter Query if FileField contains data

Tags: python, django

in my little addressbook app i'd like to list the contacts where the field 'photo' is set.

In my model I have:

```
photo = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name, blank=True, null=True)
```

In my view I try to do:

```
complete_contacts = Contact.objects.all().filter(photo__isnull=False)
```

It seems as if "isnull=False" works for Charfields but not for my FileField. How can I filter the entries which contains a photo in my query?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks! But that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`QuerySet.exclude`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#exclude) to exclude contact with empty(`''`) photo:

```
complete_contacts = Contact.objects.exclude(photo='')
```